# Create a div in HTML when calling a function in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

So what's going is that I have a list of orders which I show in a view. When I click on the order id for a specific order in the list I want to have it expand with more detailed information about the order. I've created a order view which I want to load in the div that expands but I was thinking the smart way to do this is to have a function creating a div when the order id is clicked.
This is the template for the component:

```
<div class ="order" *ngFor="let order of orders | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 20, currentPage: pageNumber, totalItems: totalNumberOfOrders}">
    <span class="orderOrderId">{{order.orderId}}</span>
</div>
```

Basically I want `(click)="loadOrderView(order.orderId)"` and then the function should do:

```
loadOrderView(orderId): {
"Create a div and load it in my html under the specified order"
}
```

I don't want to use bootstrap, this should be easy enough but I don't really know how to proceed. What is the best and easiest way to achieve what I want, which in the end is basically for the order to expand and more information be presented.

Comment: I'm sure 1/10 of the code would allow to demonstrate the problem as well https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I shortened the code example

Comment: I think you should just add a component for the order details and use `*ngIf` `<div class="order" *ngFor="....; let i=index"><order-detail *ngIf="expanded[i]"></order-detail></div>`.

Comment: Can I load the component just by writing `<order-detail...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should let Angular deal with DOM manipulation.
So you should have a inner div with *`ngIf` and when the data comes from the server, you should set it to `true` and let angular render inner div.

**For example:**

```
<div class ="order" *ngFor="let order of orders | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 20, currentPage: pageNumber, totalItems: totalNumberOfOrders}" 
    (click)="loadOrderView(order)">
    <span class="orderOrderId">{{order.orderId}}</span>
    <div *ngIf="order.hasDetail">
        <order-detail [data]="order"></order-detail>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Inside your component:**

```
loadOrderView(order) {
    // fetch data 
  order.hasDetail = true;
}
```

Comment: And then I want to load a component in that div that expands if hasDetail is true. How do I do that from inside the function?

Comment: Just put your component inside that div. When the `ngIf statement` becomes true, angular will render that component.

Comment: How do I load a component in the html? Can I just write ` <name of component></name of component>`?

Comment: Okey perfect thank you. Let's see how that works out.

Comment: `<div *ngIf="hasDetail">
        <order [order]="order"></order>
  </div>`

Would this transfer the order for the selected order to the  order component? So I can load the correct order details?

*Edit: I meant the order, not the orderId*

Comment: Yes you can bind anything to any attribute of `Order` component annotated with `@Input` decorator.